# Using a foreign key - only 2 records?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

Should I use a foreign key for "balanceimpact" that only has two options either "CREDIT" or "DEBIT"?

Does it even make sense, there are only two options here?

Comment: It really depends on the situation.  If you are talking about a simple database, it probably isn't worth creating a separate table.  If it is something more complex, then you may want to consider a table so that you can attach additional information to the "CREDIT" and "DEBIT" values.

Comment: If it's really only ever going to be two values, you could use a CHECK constraint on the column. If there's even a remote chance there might be a third, fourth option - make it a regular lookup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much as how many options there are, but what kind of rel this is (1:1; 1:n; etc).

On this particular case, I wouldn't use a foreign key, just leave it as a column.

Also, as Marc_S suggested on his comment, add a CHECK constraint to ensure that only one of those 2 values are entered.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_balanceimpact CHECK (balanceimpact in ('C','D'))
GO
```

Comment: ..as a column **with a CHECK constraint** to at least make sure only one of those two values is entered...

Comment: @marc_s thanks, Marc. With your permission, I will add your comment  to the answer.

Comment: I'd use TomTom's approach. With lareg tablkes, this makes a difference to storage: 1 byte vs an average of ~7.5 bytes (includes 2 for length). Which affects page density. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/when-to-use-tinyint-over-int/4979#4979

Comment: @gbn thanks. Updated the constraint to use C,D as TomTom suggests

Answer (score 1):

Famous words "There will only be two options"

Not to split a hair 20 ways but, I have a slightly different approach when seeing this. I say create a lookup table with a fk. Only because when they want to add the 3rd, 4th, and .. options you will have all the structure in place.  Obviously in this case you can go either way and be fine, I just don't see why it's so bad to normalize it up front to begin with and avoid any rework in the future even if there is a slight chance of it.  Just my 2cents of the top of my head late at night.

Comment: Using the C, D approach allows this to be change to a lookup later with a char(1) FK.

Comment: That's my point why have to change it to a lookup later when you can just do it now.  To me that implies the correct way to do it is to use a lookup table to begin with. Even if that change is simple to do in practice the sum of the whole change might not be. One of a few examples I can think of... What if they have 5 trillion records with C and D and you have to run an update on C and D to make it a 1 and 2 on all those records it might have more impact that what it appears.

Comment: why is it famous words? :) in accounting there are only CREDIT and DEBIT :)

Comment: Oh I'm sure someone will come up with something new it's the law of nature digital or biological. Something like partial credit and reverse debit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to have two options it seems that the better solution would be just to have a column that is true/false. Unless it's mapping to other tables.